# How to use alias to simplify CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES

Tags: alias, git-bash

I can use `alias gpu0='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0'` to set gpu0, but what if `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2`?

Comment: `alias gpu012='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2'`? But a shell function that takes arguments would probably be better.

Comment: but it will be tedious if I have 8 gpus...maybe I need to write a script to generate it

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a bash function to this. Put this function inside .bashrc:

```
gpu() {
  export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="$1"
}
```

and use it with `gpu 0` or `gpu 0,1`

Comment: got error "syntax error near unexpected token `('  `gpu() {'

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73697960/how-to-simplify-cuda-visible-devices-0-1-6-7

Answer (score -1):

share my script to generate all possible alias situation

```
import itertools
num = 8
gpu_list = []
for i in range(num):
    gpu_list.extend(list(itertools.combinations(
        [str(j) for j in range(num)], i + 1)))
print(gpu_list)
f = open('gpu.txt', 'w')
for gpu in gpu_list:
    sub1 = ''.join(gpu)
    sub2 = ','.join(gpu)
    f.writelines(f"alias gpu{sub1}=\'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={sub2}\'\n")
```

Comment: since I the shell-function answer above does not work well for me, I think this answer is a practical walk-around ; )