# How to simplify CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,6,7

Tags: bash, alias, multi-gpu

Every time when I start training, I need to manully type a command like `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,6,7`, depending on how many GPUs I am going to use and which ones are currently free.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707855/how-to-use-alias-to-simplify-cuda-visible-devices) offered an ugly yet practical workaround. I.e. write an alias in `.bashrc` for every combination:

```
alias gpu4='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4'
alias gpu25='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,5'
alias gpu256='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,5,6'
alias gpu0467='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,4,6,7'
```

This, for example, could save much time from typing `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'.

How to further simplify the use of `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`?

Or, could anyone share a more elegant way to replace the `alias` list above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple function like this, perhaps?

```
cuda () {
    local devs=$1
    shift
    CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="$devs" "$@"
}
```

You'd run it like

```
cuda 2,3,7 command --options
```

Generally, prefer functions over aliases.